# Fastest way of data transfer between applications running on same computer

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have two applications running on a same computer which should share data between both about 20 times in a second .

Application 1 generates a line of string data for example "1-ABC-XYZ-3-HK" and it wants to pass this data to application 2.

Then Application 2 does something  and discards that data.

What I have done is now Application 1 keep generating the data and store to a SQL database file, while application 2 will be constantly monitoring that same SQL file and whenever there is new data it picks that and does something then moves that data to another table marked as processed. This process happens about 20 times in a second.

Application 2 has a timer control which query the data base file 50 times in a second to monitor if there is any new data.

My question is this...

Is there any faster or better way to transfer this data than I explained above? I'm not sure whether querying a database 50 times a second is good or bad and could reduce the performance of the PC.

Application 1 is generating data and recording 20 times a second at the same time application 2 querying same data base 50 times. Please help me if there is any professional way.

Comment: You could instead let each application write to the others `stdin`.

Comment: MSMQ,Producer/Consumer

Comment: If you just want to send data from one  process to another on the same machine, I wouldn't use a DB.  I can think of several options: a socket, a named pipe, a memory mapped file.

Comment: A database is a very slow way to pass information between processes.  It would be much faster to use named pipes or WCF for proper inter-process communication.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Tcp socket to transfer the data from one application to the next. And you can serialized the data using the Protocol Buffers.

Answer (score 1):

you can try use a named pipe , take this two below as a examples

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/441841/Csharp-Named-Pipes-with-Async
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492231/Csharp-Async-Named-Pipes

Hope this can help